# Django REST Swagger: How to add oauth2/token endpoint

Tags: python, django, swagger, django-swagger

I'm using django-rest-swagger version 2.1.1.
I used the oauth2_provider.urls to build the oauth2/token endpoint like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^oauth2/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
]
```

The issue is that the Swagger don't detect it as endpoint so it's missing form my openapi.json file.

What can I do to this endpoint in order to be able to detected by Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default TokenView class of oauth2_provider as follow :

views.py :

```
class TokenAPIView(TokenView, APIView):
    schema = ManualSchema(fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            "client_id",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String()
        ),
        coreapi.Field(
            "client_secret",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String()
        ),
        coreapi.Field(
            "grant_type",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String()
        ),
    ])
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    server_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_SERVER_CLASS
    validator_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS
    oauthlib_backend_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create an oauth2 token
        """
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And also replace the default get_schema_view :

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_swagger import renderers


class SwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    exclude_from_schema = True
    renderer_classes = [
        renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
        renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
    ]

    def get(self, request):
        generator = SchemaGenerator(title='API Endpoints')
        schema = generator.get_schema()
        return Response(schema)
```

urls.py :

```
oauth2_endpoint_views = [
    url(r'^token/$', TokenAPIView.as_view(), name="token"),
]

url(r'^$', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
url(r'^oauth/', include(oauth2_endpoint_views, namespace="oauth2_provider")),
```